# Laravel 6 DOMPDF image rendering

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf** to convert Blade template views into PDF documents, everything works great except imagery.

In one PDF I have an image with the following markup.

```
<img 
    class="newable-logo" 
    src="{{ public_path('assets/images/newable-logo-blue.png') }}"
    alt="{{ public_path('assets/images/newable-logo-blue.png') }}"
>
```

On my local machine, this resolves to

`C:\laragon\www\nvl-portal\public\assets/images/newable-logo-blue.png`

This doesn't render on the PDF locally but this exact code works as expected on my staging and production servers.

Is this normal behaviour?

I always thought DOMPDF used the fully qualified path?

Answer (score 0):

it can happen due to path separator deference between windows and linux.
you can try DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in php.
eg:

```
src="{{ public_path('assets' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'images' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'newable-logo-blue.png') }}"
```